# Relation between a group homomorphism and the composition with itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\varphi :G \longrightarrow G$ a group homomorphism. To prove:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}$
$$\Ker(\varphi)=\Ker(\varphi^2) \iff \Im(\varphi)=\Im(\varphi^2)$$

I have some tools but I'm not able to combine them effectively. If $x\in \Ker(\varphi)$, then $\varphi(\varphi(x))=\varphi(e_G)=e_G$, hence $\Ker(\varphi) \subseteq \Ker(\varphi^2)$.
With the first isomorphism theorem follows $\Im(\varphi) \cong \Im(\varphi^2)$.

Any hints?

Comment: If $\ker\varphi=\ker\varphi^{2}$ then that means that $\varphi$ fixes the kernel, i.e. $\varphi(\ker\varphi)=\ker\varphi$. This then means that the image of a coset of the kernel is also a coset of the kernel. Also note that different cosets cannot be mapped to the same coset.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first isomorphism theorem is a good step! It gives $\text{Im}(\varphi)\cong G/\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ and $\text{Im}(\varphi^2)\cong G/\text{Ker}(\varphi^2)$. This should make one direction easy, for the other direction you have already made the first important observation. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment but It doesn't really say anything more than I said myself...

Comment: For $\Leftarrow$, what does my hint tell you about the index of both kernels in $G$?

Comment: They have the same cardinality and since $G$ is finite and one inclusion always holds, then they are equal. That's a little step that I was missing, thank you. Any similar hints on how to prove $\Rightarrow$?